# Behat 3: How to get profile name inside FeatureContext

Tags: php, behat, mink, autotest

I am starting behat with

```
./bin/behat --suite=SuiteName --profile=profile_name
```

Is it possible to get current behat profile name inside FeatureContext especially inside `BeforeSuiteScope`

```
/**
 * @BeforeSuite
 */
public static function beforeSuite(BeforeSuiteScope $scope)
{
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found brute force method, I know probably its not the best way of getting profile name, but it works.

```
$input   = new ArgvInput($_SERVER['argv']);
$profile = $input->getParameterOption(array('--profile', '-p')) ? : 'default';
var_dump($profile);die;
```

And `ArgvInput`  is `Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput`

Thats how cli params parsing done in behat.