# Get the behat profile name in a context

Tags: bdd, behat, mink

How do I get the profile name that I'm running currently in a future context. Id didn't find any behat documentation on running this. I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520667/behat-3-how-to-get-profile-name-inside-featurecontext) related to my question. But is there a better way of getting profile name that the test is currently running on?

My expected results change based on the profile that I'm running.

Comment: Can you use something else other than profile? like base_url? Have you considered adding a parameter for each profile? Or have you tried to create some logic based on the URL or some attribute of the page like meta, lang or any unique element in the page for each profile?

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the suggestion. I have used  `$baseurl = $this->getMinkParameter('base_url');` to get the profile I'm using. And using if-else statement, I'm comparing my expected result. It is my overlook about base_url parameter in profile.

Answer (score 1):

```
$baseurl = $this->getMinkParameter('base_url');
```

Using the $baseurl parameter, it is possible to differentiate between the profiles. Thank you @lauda